# Selecting random results within Doctrine

Tags: php, random, doctrine

I'm new to Doctrine and had a hard time deciding how to get random rows within it without creating custom DQL functions or using a native query.
The solution I have come up with is below. This is within a custom repository for an Entity. I'm hoping for some constructive criticism in regards to it, however it currently is working.

```
class MyRepository extends EntityRepository
{

/**
 * @param int $numberOfResults
 * @return array
 */
public function getRandomResults($numberOfResults = 1)
{
    $maxID = $this->getMax();
    $count = 0;
    $randomNumberCounter = 0;
    $randomNumbers = array();
    while ($randomNumberCounter < $numberOfResults) {
        $randomNumberCounter++;
        $randomNumbers[] = $this->getRandom(0, $maxID);
    }

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    while ($count < $numberOfResults) {
        $qb
            ->andWhere(
                $qb->expr()->orX(
                    // the greater than is to account for holes within the primary key
                    $qb->expr()->gte("r.id", "?".$count),
                    /* the less than is in case we have a beginning database with a large disparity
                    between starting and ending ID */
                    $qb->expr()->lte("r.id", "?".$count)
                )
            );
        $count++;
    }
    $result = $qb
        ->setParameters($randomNumbers)
        ->setMaxResults($numberOfResults)
        // ensure we have no duplicates
        ->groupBy('r.id')
        ->getQuery();

    return $result->getResult();
}


/**
 * get the maximum ID that the table has
 * @return mixed
 * TODO: Create a Cron job to set this every 6 hours
 */
public function getMax()
{
    $maxID = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->select('(MAX(r.id))')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
    return $maxID;
}

/**
 * @param $min
 * @param $max
 * @return int
 */
public function getRandom($min, $max)
{
    return mt_rand($min, $max);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good thing your code works, it's a prerequisite for code that's ready for a peer review ;-)

Comment: The problem with your code is that the ID is supposed to begin from 0 and will not work if you delete some rows in the database.

Comment: @talibe, where do you see this starting from 0? I also believe the < and > filters allow for gaps. Either way, I have a more performant method that I will update this with.

Comment: If in the table you delete some rows the database will not reorder the IDs. So if you delete the row where `id=1`, there will be no row corresponding for `id=1` any more. Your code will try to find that row and it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

## Increment operator ➕➕ can be moved up after usage in `while` loop

In the first `while` loop to add numbers to `$randomNumbers` the value of `$randomNumberCounter` is incremented on a separate line:

> ```
> $randomNumberCounter++;
> ```

That operation could be combined in the condition of the `while` loop:

```
while ($randomNumberCounter++ < $numberOfResults) {
    $randomNumbers[] = $this->getRandom(0, $maxID);
}
```

## There are simpler ways to add numbers in a loop

The block to add to `$randomNumbers` could be simplified. Instead of using the `while` loop a `for` loop could be used:

```
for($randomNumberCounter = 0; $randomNumberCounter < $numberOfResults; $randomNumberCounter++) {
    $randomNumbers[] = $this->getRandom(0, $maxID);
}
```

A `foreach` loop could also be used with [`range()`](https://www.php.net/range) function:

```
foreach(range(1, $numberOfResults) as $i) {
    $randomNumbers[] = $this->getRandom(0, $maxID);
}
```

While it may be the least efficient, a functional approach could be used to assign the array in a single statement using [`array_fill()`](https://www.php.net/array_fill) and [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
$randomNumbers = array_map(
    fn($number) => $this->getRandom(0, $maxID),
    array_fill(0, $numberOfResults, 0)
);
```

## Current approach does not ensure all random numbers will be unique

Perhaps it would be better to ensure that a random number is not already in the array of random numbers before adding it to the array.

## Add spaces around boolean operators for readability

Adhering to a standard is not required but it does help with readability when the style is consistent. Many PHP developers follow [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) like [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). While it wasn't approved until 2019, [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) replaced [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) which was approved in 2012.

In PSR-12 is section 6 concerning [Operators](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#6-operators)

> #### 6.2. Binary operators
>
> All binary [arithmetic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), [logical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), and [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) operators MUST be preceded and followed by at least one space:

> ```
> if ($a === $b) {
>     $foo = $bar ?? $a ?? $b;
> } elseif ($a > $b) {
>     $foo = $a + $b * $c;
> }
> ```

Some binary operators in the code above are preceeded and followed by a space - e.g.

> ```
> $maxID = $this->getMax();
> ```

However, other places do not- e.g.

> ```
> $qb->expr()->gte("r.id", "?".$count),
> ```

Since double quotes are used `$count` could be moved into the string, since variables are parsed within double-quoted strings<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)</sup> which would eliminate the need to append with `.`:

```
$qb->expr()->gte("r.id", "?$count"),
```